# Parse big file for found values using python

Tags: python, chunks

I have two files:

- fileA with 20,000 lines
- fileB with 16000000 of lines

I want to compare the the line[3] from fileA with line[1] from fileB.

flieA format:

```
1       i713426 0       726912  0       0
1       i713449 0       830731  0       0
1       i707010 0       1183442 0       A
1       i713034 0       1225231 0       G
1       i703639 0       1267327 I       D
1       i713057 0       1425512 0       T
1       i713129 0       1501061 0       G
1       i707027 0       1542721 0       C
1       i713163 0       1680617 0       C
1       i707055 0       1884055 0       C
1       i713254 0       2145254 0       C
1       i713324 0       2486696 0       C
1       i6059967        0       2526746 G       A
1       i713334 0       2626131 0       0
1       i713335 0       2692373 0       C
1       i713341 0       3043138 0       A
1       i707150 0       3216645 0       0
1       i713347 0       3277176 0       G
```

fileB fromat

```
chr1    87190   rs1524602   A/G 0.4358974358974359  0.8
chr1    87204   rs866881507 A/G 0.02564102564102564 0.2
chr1    87234   rs533355948 C/T 0.02564102564102564 0.2
chr1    87236   rs879825293 C/T 0.05128205128205128 0.2
chr1    87256   rs373216495 C/T 0.05128205128205128 0.6
chr1    87259   rs570089526 A/G 0.05128205128205128 0.6
chr1    87302   rs529420236 C/T 0.02564102564102564 0.2
chr1    87303   rs2103135   A/G 0.1282051282051282  0.4
chr1    87304   rs550004764 A/G 0.02564102564102564 0.2
chr1    87351   rs549570359 C/T 0.02564102564102564 0.2
chr1    87360   rs180907504 C/T 0.15384615384615385 0.6
chr1    87361   rs535266627 A/G 0.02564102564102564 0.4
chr1    87366   rs558417557 A/G 0.02564102564102564 0.4
chr1    87373   rs963638476 A/G 0.02564102564102564 0.2
chr1    87374   rs974579646 A/C 0.02564102564102564 0.2
```

output if line[3] from fileA is equal line[1] from fileB print

```
i713426 rs567161598
i713449 rs547376081
i707010 rs566056983
i713034 rs568184696
i703639 rs748522325
i713057 rs528436382
i713129 rs560208264
i707027 rs532649680
i713163 rs577119367
i707055 rs566696367
i713254 rs554477909
i713324 rs542280290
```

my code

```
with open('/////fileA','r') as bim:
    with open ('////output.isec', 'w') as ic:
        for k in bim:
            l1 = k.split('\t')
            size = len(str(l1[3]))
            with open('/fileB', 'r') as file:
                for m in file:
                    l2 = m.split('\t')
                    if len(l2[1]) != size:
                        continue
                    if l1[3] == l2[1]:
                        if l1[1] != l2[2]:
                            #print(l1[1],l2[2])
                            ic.write('{0}\t{1}\n'.format(l1[1],l2[2]))
                        break
```

The script (B(k^2)) takes approximately 30 min for 900 lines from fileA, how can modify my script to improve the time?

Comment: use maps with maps you can have a linear complexity , or simply don't use python that is a really slow language. it should be used for scripting where time is not important. Or use cython to improve performance

Comment: The samples you provide contain no overlapping values.

Comment: Do these files each only contain chromosome 1?

Comment: Does fileB contain lines of comments starting with ## at the top of the file?

Comment: @ErikMcKelvey the file is from  snp151.txt from dbsnp, I builded chunks files with 1-22 chromosome, the file has not starting with ## like vcf or dtc file

Comment: @Edomfra Have you tried out my answer?

Comment: @ErikMcKelvey yes but not works, bim_line = '' (empty) , I don't know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since both the files are sorted, you only need to iterate through each one once, and read the next line of the file with a lower position. This should only take a few minutes:

```
bim = open('/////fileA','r')
ic = open('////output.isec', 'w')
file = open('/fileB', 'r')
bim_line = bim.readline()
line = file.readline()
while line and bim_line:
    bim_split = bim_line.split("\t")
    split = line.split("\t")
    if bim_split[3] < split[1]:
        bim_line = bim.readline()
    elif split[1] < bim_split[3]:
        line = file.readline()
    else:
        ic.write(bim_split[1] + "\t" + split[2] + "\n")
        line = file.readline()
        bim_line = bim.readline()
bim.close()
ic.close()
file.close()
```